# create Postgress view to combine multiple tables data

Tags: postgresql

I have multiple tables with different column names like below,

**customer table**:
c_id,
customer_name,
phone_number,
postal_code

**Employee Table**: Employee_name, e_id, mobile_no,zip_code

**student Table**: s_id, student_name, post_code

I need to create view to combine those tables like below

**User Table**: userId (c_id, e_id, s_id), userName (all name columns), zip_code, contact

**Sample Data**

Customer Table:

```
|  c_id  |  Company_Name  |  Phone |
|----------------------------------|
|  1     |  Company 1     | *******|
|----------------------------------|
```

Employee Table:

```
|  e_id  |  Employee_Name | Mobile |
|----------------------------------|
|  1     |  employee 1    | *******|
|----------------------------------|
```

Expected View:

```
|  userId  |   user_Name   | contact  |
|-------------------------------------|
|  c_1     |   Company 1   |  ******* |
|-------------------------------------|
|  e_1     |   employee 1  |  ******* |
|-------------------------------------|
```

how to create the view please help me, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `Union` or `Union All` depending on duplicate values. based on data

```
CREATE VIEW view_name
AS
  SELECT concat('c_',c_id)         AS userId,
         company_name AS user_Name,
         phone        AS contact
  FROM   customer
  UNION
  SELECT concat('e_',e_id),
         employee_name,
         mobile
  FROM   employee
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=88f7473090fc386cdc66dfbd30c37111)

based on tables

```
CREATE VIEW view_name
AS
  SELECT c_id          AS userId,
         customer_name AS userName,
         postal_code   AS zip_code,
         phone_number  AS contact
  FROM   customer
  UNION
  SELECT e_id,
         employee_name,
         zip_code,
         mobile_no
  FROM   employee
  UNION
  SELECT s_id,
         student_name,
         post_code,
         NULL
  FROM   student
```